# No such module "PackageDescription"

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I just started with swift 3 and made a simple app in xcode using Swift 3.0 . Now i want to add a third party [library](https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren) using Swift Package Manager . I am following installation method given in this link . I created `Package.swift` file which looks like this

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package (
name : "SwiftPM",
dependencies : [
.Package(url: "https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren.git", majorVersion: 1)
])
```

but i get error `No such module "PackageDescription"`

Answer (score 19):

For me the issue turned out to be `Target Membership`. I created the `Package.swift` file manually inside an iOS app project.

Solution:

- Select and go to the `Package.swift` file
- Open the `File Inspector` on the right side
- Deselect any modules inside `Target Membership` section

[image]

Comment: Yeah! it's easily overlooked.

Comment: In my case just unticking the target box didn't work. I had to delete the file, then add it back to the project making sure no target boxes were ticked at that point.

Answer (score 19):

Refer to the solution in this link:

> https://forums.kodeco.com/t/server-error-no-such-module-packagedescription/177438

Command:

```
sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: This was the fix that worked for me.

Comment: This has helped me too when encountered the issue with Tuist packages fetching and project generation.

Answer (score 16):

The Swift Package Manager and Xcode are orthogonal.  That is, you can't expect to compile Package.swift in Xcode; it simply won't work.  Instead, until Xcode supports the package manager, you need to have two distinct builds - one with the package manager and one with Xcode.

So, using the Swift Package Manager, once you've defined Package.swift and formulated your directory structure as expected by the package manger, you perform simply:

```
swift build
```

Then for Xcode, you create an Xcode project that uses your source code, but not Package.swift.  You'll need to clone the Siren.git project, explicitly - into your Xcode build's source files.

Comment: i did tried to import all Siren files explicitly and paste them into my xcode , but that was also not working

Comment: Perhaps the Siren.git project has dependencies itself?  If so, for your Xcode build, you'll need to download all the dependencies explicitly and include them in the Xcode build.  If not that, you'll need to update your question with more details - showing the errors.

Comment: I recommend using a `git submodule` if you need to clone the dependency into your xcode project.

Comment: Hi, I created Siren and just came across this post. Please leave an issue on the Siren repo if this is still an issue: https://github.com/ArtSabintsev/Siren/issues

Answer (score 12):

**Swift 3/4**

Navigate to your project folder through a terminal and run these commands `swift package init --type library` first and then `swift package generate-xcodeproj`

[Reference](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-package-error-root-manifest-not-found/15605)

Answer (score 5):

For other people who faced the same error as this:

## Fix your `Package.swift` syntax

I got this error because Xcode hadn't parsed `Package.swift` fully yet, because of syntax errors.

In my case, I had a `.target(name: "name-of-target", dependencies: [""])`. As soon as I **removed the empty dependency string (`""`)**, Xcode immediately parsed the file, and the error disappeared. Remember to save the file though.

#### Also, GoZoner and Pratiks answers are outdated:

- Xcode has integration with Swift Packages now (as shown above)
- `swift package generate-xcodeproj` is deprecated, shown by the error message when using it:

> **warning:** Xcode can open and build Swift Packages directly. 'generate-xcodeproj' is no longer needed and will be deprecated soon.

More information about what that is, and why its gone [here](https://forums.swift.org/t/generate-xcodeproj-is-no-longer-needed-and-will-be-deprecated-soon/48995).

Comment: But I ran into this error without such empty dependency string, how should I deal with it?

Comment: Check the syntax of your `Package.swift`. Restart Xcode and it will give you different error messages, I find that to be helpful when trying to understand what's going wrong.